# Vue.js Keyboard events not working

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, keyboard-events

I'm tring to build a piano that will play a note depending on the key pressed on the keyboard. A user will click on input and after click for example 'a' it will play note C2. My current code doesn't work, nor it shows any errors in the console, so I was wondering what have I done wrong. I'm a bit new to Vue.js

Here is HTML:

```
<input type="text" v-on:keyup = "keyMonitor"/>
```

Here is JS file:

```
var wrapper = new Vue({
el: '#wrapper',
data: {
notes: [
{key: 65, name: "C2.mp3"},
{key: 83, name: "D2.mp3"},
{key: 68, name: "E2.mp3"},
{key: 70, name: "F2.mp3"},
{key: 71, name: "G2.mp3"},
{key: 72, name: "A2.mp3"},
{key: 74, name: "B2.mp3"},
{key: 75, name: "C3.mp3"},
{key: 76, name: "D3.mp3"},
{key: 90, name: "E3.mp3"},
{key: 88, name: "F3.mp3"},
{key: 67, name: "G3.mp3"},
{key: 86, name: "A3.mp3"},
{key: 66, name: "B3.mp3"},
{key: 78, name: "C4.mp3"},
{key: 77, name: "D4.mp3"},
{key: 188, name: "E4.mp3"}
]
},
methods: {
playNote: function(note){
    if(note){
        var audio = new Audio(note);
        audio.play();

    }
},
keyMonitor: function(evt){
for(var key in wrapper.notes)
    if(evt.key == wrapper.notes.key){
        playNote(wrapper.notes.name);

    }
}

}

})
```

Comment: [Here is your code cleaned up a bit](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/MXaPwb?editors=1010). It doesn't play the notes because it obviously doesn't have the mp3 files but it should get you closer.

Comment: Thank you so much it helped a lot!